# clojure behavior of meta function

Tags: clojure

Why is the behavior of meta different for a function that I define vs one that is in clojure/core? Ex:

```
user=> (defn pr-x [x] (println x))
#'user/pr-x
user=> (meta pr-x)
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name pr-x}
user=> (meta (var pr-x))
{:ns #<Namespace user>, :name pr-x, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :line 13, :arglists ([x])}
user=> (meta map)
{:ns #<Namespace clojure.core>, :name map, :file "clojure/core.clj", :line 2079, :arglists ([f coll] [f c1 c2] [f c1 c2 c3] [f c1 c2 c3 & colls]), :added "1.0", :doc "Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to the\n  set of first items of each coll, followed by applying f to the set\n  of second items in each coll, until any one of the colls is\n  exhausted.  Any remaining items in other colls are ignored. Function\n  f should accept number-of-colls arguments."}
user=>
```

Note that I must call `(meta (var pr-x))` for a user defined function to get the metadata, whereas a function in clojure core I can just go `(meta map)` and get the metadata. I don't understand; why the difference?

Comment: try it: (defn pr-x "doc" {:ver "0.1"} [x] (println x)) (meta pr-x);when define default meta , setting meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version are you using? With 1.3, I get consistent behavior. `(meta map)` returns nil for me, but `(meta (var map))` returns `{:ns #<Namespace clojure.core>, :name map, :arglists ([f coll] [f c1 c2] [f c1 c2 c3] [f c1 c2 c3 & colls]), :added "1.0", :static true, :doc "Returns a lazy sequence consisting of the result of applying f to the\n  set of first items of each coll, followed by applying f to the set\n  of second items in each coll, until any one of the colls is\n  exhausted.  Any remaining items in other colls are ignored. Function\n  f should accept number-of-colls arguments.", :line 2414, :file "clojure/core.clj"}`

Comment: 1.2, I guess I'll upgrade to 1.3